# WTForms StringField Dynamic Default Value using datetime.utcnow / Callable?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a WTForm with the following:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    ...
    timestamp = DateTimeField("Timestamp", default = datetime.utcnow, validators = [Required()])
    name = StringField("Name", default = str(int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp())), validators = [Optional()])
    ...
```

Upon creating a new form the default timestamp field updates as expected while the default name field continues to use the timestamp of when the app was started. I can successfully set the timestamp in my route, my preference is to utilize the default functionality of the form. Looking here:

[The Field base class](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#the-field-base-class)

It states that default "May be a callable." but I haven't been able to find a working example of this. I'm assuming if I make this a callable, the default value will update with current timestamp. Does anyone know how to make default get its value from a function?

Thanks in advance,

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `timestamp` field, you provide a callable - `datetime.datetime.utcnow` to `default`, so each time the form is instantiated the callable is called and the new result is used.

In your `name` field, `datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()` is evaluated when the form is compiled, so the default value is the same for every instance of the form.

If you want the default value of `name` to be evaluated every time the form is instantiated, pass it a function (a callable) that returns `datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()`.

Like this:

```
def get_default():
    datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()


class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    timestamp = DateTimeField("Timestamp", default=datetime.utcnow, validators=[Required()])
    name = StringField("Name", default=get_default, validators=[Optional()])
```

or if you prefer, you can use a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions):

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    timestamp = DateTimeField("Timestamp", default=datetime.utcnow, validators=[Required()])
    name = StringField("Name", default=lambda : datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp(), validators=[Optional()])
```