# Changed data in Flask App is updating in Database but not in App during runtime

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

i've two tables: billtexts and zahlungsarten (kinds of payment).
every billtext has it's own zahlungsart (kind of payment).
zahlungsarten is just a selectiontable - to select the zahlungsarten for the billtext entries from.

by adding new billtexts (or modifying one) the zahlungsart entry is selectable in a selection field.

i can add new billtexts, everything works fine. but when i add a new zahlungsart (or modify one) to zahlungsarten (the selectiontable), then return to the billtext form and try to add/edit a billtext, the new zahlungsart is not shown in the selectionfield of the billtexts at runtime (allthough its in database!). If i restart the app it is shown correctly.

using a function insead of the Mixin to generate the selection_values makes no difference...

should not fetch `get_selection_values` the actual data at runtime?

Do I have to update something at runtime to get fresh inserted/modified data for selection-fields?

```
class SelZahlungsart(db.Model, GetSelectionValuesMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'sel_zahlungsart'

    idsel_zahlungsart = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, primary_key=True, info='id of the zahlungsart')
    zahlungsart = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False, info='Bezeichnung der Zahlungsart')
```

```
class GetSelectionValuesMixin(object):

    @staticmethod
    def get_selection_values(q_object, q_field):
        """
        Returns selection values of given table and column as a list.
        :param q_object: the db.Model class
        :param q_field: the db.Model class field
        :return: all values from the given Model/field
        """
        result = [r.field for r in db.session.query(q_object).with_entities(q_field.label('field')).distinct()]
        #result = [r.field for r in q_object.query.with_entities(q_field.label('field')).distinct()]
        return result
```

```
class TBilltext(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 't_billtexts'

    textid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    zahlungsart = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False, unique=True, info='kind of payment')
```

```
class BilltextForm(FlaskForm):
    """
    Form for admin to add/edit billextra
    """
    ...
    zahlungsart = SelectField(choices=SelZahlungsart.get_selection_values(SelZahlungsart, SelZahlungsart.zahlungsart))
    submit = SubmitField('Speichern')
```

and the view:

```
add_billtext = True
    form = BilltextForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        billtext = TBilltext(...,
                             zahlungsart=form.zahlungsart.data)
        return (add_dataset(billtext, "Neuer Rechnungstext erfolgreich hinzugefügt",
                            "Fehler beim Hinzufügen des neuen Rechnungstextes!", "admin.list_billtexts"))
...
```

Seems like get_selection_values only runs once at application start up. So values can never be updated... But why does it not run each time its called?

Comment: Ok: I changed SelectField to QuerySelectField, so i do not need to Mixin the get_selection_values(). That works fine (except getting distinct values). Despite this, it would be great to understand why my Mixinclass doesnt work...

Comment: `choices` for wtforms is evaluated once, at compile time.  If you want it to  be dynamic, pass a callable, for example `choices=lambda: SelZahlungsart.get_selection_values(SelZahlungsart, SelZahlungsart.zahlungsart)`.  [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53459787/5320906)